# Does Cube.js support preAggregations when using Context Variables inside the SQL definition of a cube?

Tags: javascript, sql, analytics, cube.js

According to the [Cube.js documentation](https://cube.dev/docs/cube#context-variables-user-context), one can define cubes using something called Context Variables, that allows the injection of filters (such as a particular user email) when querying that cube.
I haven't tried it yet, but I want to know if this feature is compatible with preaggregations, and also if it handles empty filter cases.
For example, if I define this cube (same as the example from the docs):

```js
    cube(`OrderFacts`, {
      sql: `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE ${FILTER_PARAMS.OrderFacts.date.filter('date')}`,

      measures: {
        count: {
          type: `count`
        }
      },

      dimensions: {
        date: {
          sql: `date`,
          type: `time`
        }
      }
    });
```

will I be able to define a preAggregation such as this?

```js
  preAggregations: {
    date: {
      type: `rollup`,
      measureReferences: [someMeasure],
      dimensionReferences: [someDimension],
      timeDimensionReference: date,
      granularity: `month`
    }
  }
```

and can I perform queries without a `date` dimension filter? (so the `sql` would end as `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE;`) ?

To sum up: is there a way of injecting filters to a cube's `sql` definition dynamically, but not at *query time* and instead at *schema compile time*?
I ask this because we are currently extending some cubes with information retrieved from our API, and we were overwriting the `segment` field from this cubes, but due to performance issues we would prefer to overwrite the cube's `sql` field (to filter unnecessary data from the start).

NOTE: We are using `asyncModule` to perform the queries to our API. We also need to build different cubes (for all our clients) referencing a common table, but with a dynamic SQL that will change depending on the client.

Our desired output should be (for an Orders table and `F1`, ..., `Fn` client filters from our API):
N cubes that extend a base `Orders` cube: `OrdersC1`, `OrdersC2`, ..., `OrdersCn`.
Each `OrdersCi` cube with a modified version of the base `Orders` sql, containing its `Fi` filter.
Each `OrdersCi` cube with the same `dimensions`, `measures` and `preAggregations` definitions, inherited from the base `Orders` cube.

We managed to implement all that I said before, but instead of modifying the `sql` field, we overwrote the `segments` field.

Answer (score 0):

In general only partitioned rollups pass `FILTER_PARAMS` for partitioned time dimensions. 
All other pre-aggregations doesn't allow passing context variables.
There're two approaches you can use to leverage pre-aggregations in multi-tenant environments.

1. Override `sql` for each customer cube such as `OrdersC1`, `OrdersC2`, etc. In this case all pre-aggregations defined in base `Orders` cube will be inherited. Each customer cube will have it's own set of pre-aggregations. It means if there're `N` customers and `M` pre-aggregations then `N * M` pre-aggregation tables should be built which can be costly in some scenarios.

```js
cube(`Orders`, {
  sql: `SELECT * FROM orders`,

  preAggregations: {
    date: {
      type: `rollup`,
      measureReferences: [someMeasure],
      dimensionReferences: [someDimension],
      timeDimensionReference: date,
      granularity: `month`
    },
    // ...
  }
});

cube(`OrdersC1`, {
  extends: Orders,
  sql: `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE customer_id = 'C1'`,
});
```

2. Use tenant field as a dimension of rollup. Every segment can be converted to dimension which provides an opportunity to use single rollup table for all customers. To route requests to right tenant data [queryTransformer](https://cube.dev/docs/@cubejs-backend-server-core#options-reference-query-transformer) can be used.

```js
cube(`Orders`, {
  sql: `SELECT * FROM orders`,

  // ...

  dimensions: {
    // ...

    customerId: {
      sql: `customer_id`,
      type: `string`
    }
  },

  preAggregations: {
    date: {
      type: `rollup`,
      measureReferences: [someMeasure],
      dimensionReferences: [customerId, someDimension],
      timeDimensionReference: date,
      granularity: `month`
    },

    // ...
  }
});
```